# Stop Autoresizing when UIDevice Orientation changes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6, orientation, uideviceorientation

I'm having a quite annoying problem with iOS 6.0.
Everytime the IUDevice orientation changes some subviews autoresize even if not needed.
In my particular case the only thing that autoresizes is UIButton, so what can i do stop this autoresize and if possible disable all autoresizes?

Cheers.

Comment: wthr autolayout is enabled in the xib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove autoresizing from all subview

@By Code

```
[subView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```

@By InterfaceBuilder

[image]

Comment: FYI: the autoresizing mode you've specified on the screenshot is actually `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` - it won't _resize_ the view, but it will still reposition it when superview size changes. These I-shape thingies are called "struts" and when they are in place, it means that the corresponding margin is fixed.